# Como deixar um seek bar oculto até que outro botão seja clicado - Android

Tags: android

Olá. Tenho uma duvida boba, mais que serei muito grato a quem me ajudar! Estou fazendo um app em que em uma activity possuo uma image view, varios buttons e um seekbar. A idéia é a seguinte, quero setar uma imagem na image view de acorto com o botão clicado e o valor da seek bar, por exemplo... Botão 1+ seekBar 10 = imagem x
Botao 2 + seek bar 8 = imagem y...

Para isso pensei em deixar a seekbar oculta ou travada até que que o buttom seja selecionado. e gostaria que o button permanecesse selecionado... Alguem pode me ajudar com esse código? como ficaria...

Answer (score 1):

Bem-vindo. Não consegui reproduzir exatamente a sua dúvida, portanto essa resposta assume uma SeekBar normal e um Button normal.

> "Pensei em deixar a seekbar oculta ou travada até que que o buttom seja selecionado."

Você pode definir o atributo [visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility) no layout e alterá-lo com [setVisibility(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) quando o botão for clicado OU definir o atributo enabled e alterá-lo com s[etEnabled(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)).

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    <!-- android:enabled="false" --> />



Button button = findViewById(R.id.botao);
SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //seekBar.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```